# Data types supported in EFM8BB1 (8051 Microcontroller) - C programming

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

I am trying to test different baud rates with the EFM8BB1 8051 microcontroller.  I am trying to make my code more generic, but I hit a break wall.

Below is my code, when I test my code for 38400 baud it works quite ok, but when I test for bauds greater than 38400 it doesn't work.

Here is the peace of code for 38400 baud:

```
if(bd == (int) 38400){
    // timer 1 uses SYSCLK/1/4/2*bd
        CLKSEL = 0;
        CKCON0 |= (1 << (0));
        temp = 2*4*bd;
        res =  24500000/temp;
    }
```

When I run my code for 38400 baud rate, this part of my code is executed and works perfectly on the MC.

But when I test my code for bauds greater than 38400, e.g. 115200, it doesn't work. Here is the piece of code responsible for that

```
 if(bd > (int) 38400){
            // SYSCLK = SYSCLK/1
            CLKSEL = 0;
            // timer 1 uses SYSCLK/1/1
            CKCON0 |= (1 << (3));
            temp =  bd*2;
            res = 24500000/temp;
        }
```

The value calculated here for **res** for 115200 baud evaluates to 106.336. When i hard code this value for res, my code runs well, but when it is calculated on the fly, like that of the 38400, it doesn't work as expected.

I have read on the data types supported and realized the **temp** calculation is greater than the max int that can be represented, but when I tried using **unsigned long int**  for both the 38400 and 115200 baud the code doesn't work.

**I don't know what I am missing**

**Full Code**

```
#include <SI_EFM8BB1_Register_Enums.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SBUF    SBUF0
#define SCON    SCON0
#define TI      SCON0_TI
#define TR1     TCON_TR1

const int SYSCLK = 24500000;


void delay(void)
{
    volatile unsigned short n;  // prevent compiler omission

    for (n=0; n<0xFFFF; n++) {}
}

void send(unsigned char ch)
{
    SBUF = ch;

    while (!TI);    // wait until transmitted
    TI=0;
}

void baud_gen(int bd)
{
    int res = 0;
    int temp;

    /*if(bd < (int)2400) {
        // timer 1 uses SYSCLK/16/12
        CLKSEL = (1<<(6));
        CKCON0 = 0;
        temp=16*12*2*bd;
        res = 24500000/temp;
    }

    if(bd >= (int) 2400 && bd < (int)7200 ){
        // timer 1 uses SYSCLK/4/12/2*bd
        CLKSEL = (1<<(5));
        CKCON0 = 0;
        temp = 4*12*2*bd;
        res = 24500000/temp;

    }

    if(bd >= (int) 7200 && bd < (int)38400) {

        // timer 1 uses SYSCLK/2/12/2*bd
        CLKSEL = (1<<(4));
        CKCON0 = 0;
        temp = 2*12*2*bd;
        res = 24500000/temp ;

    }*/


    if(bd > (int) 38400){
        // SYSCLK = SYSCLK/1
        CLKSEL = 0;
        // timer 1 uses SYSCLK/1/1
        CKCON0 |= (1 << (3));
        temp =  bd*2;
        res = SYSCLK/temp;
    }

    if(bd == (int) 38400){
    // timer 1 uses SYSCLK/1/4/2*bd
        CLKSEL = 0;
        CKCON0 |= (1 << (0));
        temp = 2*4*bd;
        res =  24500000/temp;
    }


    // EFM8 specific ADC configuration
    // P0.7 - ADC0
    P0MDIN &= ~(1 << (7));  // set P0.7 to analog input
    P0SKIP |= (1 << (7));   // disconnect P0.7 from digital
    ADC0MX = 7;             // connect P0.7 to ADC0 via MUX
    // ADC0 configuration - %00001|1|0|1 - SYSCLK/(1+1)|8-bit mode|no delay|gain=1
    ADC0CF = 0x0D;
    REF0CN = 0x08;          // voltage reference is VDD=3.3V
    ADC0CN0 |= (1 << (7));  // enable ADC0

    // EFM8 specific serial configuration
    // P0.4 - UART0 TX - PUSH_PULL
    // P0.5 - UART0 RX - OPEN_DRAIN
    P0MDOUT |= (1 << (4));

    XBR0 |= (1 << (0)); // cross-bar enable UART0 pins
    XBR2 |= (1 << (6)); // cross-bar enable all pins

    // 8051 serial configuration
    // UART mode %01 = 8-bit data
    // Baud rateSCON = 0x40;
    // timer 1 mode 2
    SCON = 0x40;
    TMOD = 0x20;


    TH1 = 256-res;  // Timer 1 High Byte -> divisor value from 256
    TL1 = 256-res;  // Timer 1 Low  Byte -> divisor value from 256

    TR1=1;              // Start timer



}

sbit LED = P1^4;

void main(void)
{
    unsigned short counter = 0;

    char ch, buffer[] = "----";





    baud_gen(38400);

    while (1)
    {
        unsigned char idx = 0;

        // toggle LED
        LED ^= 1;

        // ADC0 conversion
        ADC0CN0 |= (1 << (4));                  // start conversion
        while ((ADC0CN0 & (1 << (5))) == 0);    // wait for done
        ADC0CN0 &= ~(1 << (5));                 // reset

        // CAUTION: 8-bit result is bits 9:2
        counter = ((ADC0H << 8) | ADC0L);
        counter >>= 2;      // 8-bit result

        // convert to ASCII
        // buffer[0] = 0x30 + counter/1000;
        // buffer[1] = 0x30 + (counter%1000)/100;
        // bufferc 2] = 0x30 + (counter%100)/10;
        // buffer[3] = 0x30 + counter%10;

        // convert to voltage
        counter = (31*counter)/24;  // voltage 3.3V : 330/255 -> 31/24

        buffer[0] = 0x30 + (counter%1000)/100;
        buffer[1] = '.';
        buffer[2] = 0x30 + (counter%100)/10;
        buffer[3] = 0x30 + counter%10;

        while ((ch = buffer[idx++]) != 0)
            send(ch);
        send('\n');

        delay();
        delay();
        delay();
        delay();
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you 12250000/bd instead of 24500000/(bd*2) ?

Comment: do you really need to do a divide like that on an mcu like this, I generally avoid divides whenever possible (on an mcu).

Comment: likewise 122500/1152 programatically or bd/=100;  res=122500/bd, etc...

Comment: likewise res=(24500000>>3)/(bd>>2)

Comment: what frequency do you see on the scope when you do the 24500000/(bd*2)?  (send 0x55 to get a square wave)

Comment: Did you try to add an integer suffix to your integer constants? -- You could reduce your program (in the sense of a [example]) to several tries of divisions, and check what the results are. I'd use a simulator for this to see the results, or a simple program outputting the results by a fixed baudrate.

Comment: the easiest thing to do here is to create a simple non-static function type fun ( type x ) { return 24500000/x; } and examine the disassembly of that function (probably a library call then examine that).  where type is the type you are using (obviously has to be more than 16 bits unless you use the optimizations asked about above).

Comment: I have no scope,  I am using the toolStick tool from simplicity studio. I gives me random characters, i was trying to find a way in which i can see the contents of the res, but i cannot seem to achieve this.  Let me try what y'all suggested and get back to you  guys.  Sorry for the late reply, i was at work.

Comment: But what i still don't get is why the code works for 38400 baud

Comment: Also, I am using simplicity studio  and ToolStick  Terminal (for output)

Comment: I just tried you suggestions, even performing the division by subtraction, but still get random characters in toolstick

Comment: What other baudrates work? -- If you send a train of 0x55 = 'U', it might help to identify the problems. This characters is sent as a alternating sequence of 0 and 1 bits. -- However, this is poking in the dark. Better get your calculation straight, methodically. Look into the assembly, use a simulator, anything to check that the quotient gives you the expected result.